# How can you tell if any Activity in your application is foregrounded?

Tags: android, service

I've got an Android app which has a periodic background Service.  I want this Service to react differently depending on whether *any* Activities in my application are open.  The issue is that the Service just keeps itself running via the `AlarmManager` making it on kind of on a separate "track" from the Activities, so I don't know whether the application is open when it runs.

The best solution I can think of is to flip a boolean on/off whenever onResume() or onPause() is called in all my Activities, but this seems like a lot of footwork.  Is there a simpler, more elegant solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simpler, more elegant
>   solution?

Well, it depends a bit on what "react differently" means.

Let's suppose you want to raise a `Notification` if your activities are not in the foreground, but you want to pop a dialog if an activity is in the foreground.

In that case, you need some communication path from the service to the activity anyway. So, register a callback (supplied by the activity) with the service in `onResume()` and unregister it in `onPause()`. Your service uses the callback if one exists; if there is no callback, it raises the `Notification`.

You could accomplish the same thing with a broadcast `Intent` (register/unregister the receiver in the activity in `onResume()`/`onPause()`) if you wanted.